# How can I use polling to trigger a build, and then handle my own git operations

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

The jenkins git plugin on windows is very slow. It is taking upwards of 8 minutes to clone a 5 mb repository. I've read multiple reasons why this might be, but I have yet to find a solution that works. So what I have I tried?

- making sure jenkins service is running under an administrative account
- swapping plink in for native ssh. No love.
- optimizing git plugin config by setting the refspec, using shallow clone and not deleting the workspace. Insanely enough, adding a refspec with a shallow clone option seems to cause two fetches.One with a * ref spec and depth=1, and another with the defined refspec and no depth set.

So now what I would like to do is handle my own Git operations.

How could this be accomplished using the SCM polling mechanism? There does not seem to be any way to tell the SCM polling not to start fetching when it detects a change. Ideally I would just like the job to kick off when it detects a change, without triggering the git fetching.

Versions

- jenkins 1.5.9
- git 2.3.1
- git-client 1.12.0
- github 1.10
- github-api 1.59
- mysysgit 1.9.4

Note
I would like to note that updating the version stack above to the latest fixed most of the git slowness. I also stopped cleaning out the directory after every build, and just clean out build artifacts after running. This makes it so git does not need to download the whole repository every time. My builds are now taking under a minute.

That being said, it doesn't answer the original question, how can I use polling to trigger a build, and then handle my own git operations. So I am leaving this open for now.

Comment: What version of Jenkins, and what version of the git plugin? Where is the cloning being done to?

Comment: And which version of the windows git runtime are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could configure the git plugin to use the native Java implementation. See "Why Not JGit" at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin.

Another suggestion: you should make sure jenkins is executing the git.exe and not a wrapper script like git.bat